# Double Clicking header to sort with merged cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where i have headers for columns in Row 4. I had a code that when i double clicked on a cell in row 4 it sorted the data by that cell. The problem i have now is that in Column B, the cells are merged with the row below. So, for example row 4 and 5 are merged, row 6 and 7 etc. The code i have will no longer let me sort, due to these merged cells. Can anyone help?

Here is the code that i was using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
lc = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If Target.row = 4 And Target.Column <= lc Then Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(lr, lc)).Sort Key1:=Cells(4, Target.Column), Header:=xlYes 'Order1:=xlDescending

End Sub
```

As requested an image of my sheet [image: Sheet]

Comment: You can't sort merged cells unless all the cells in the range are the same size. You're going to have to fix that problem first.

Comment: Can you show your sheet image?

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: I modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim lc As Integer
    lc = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column <= lc Then
        sortdescent Target.Column - 1, lc
    End If
End Sub
```

module code

```
Sub sortdescent(x As Integer, col As Integer)
    Dim vDB
    Dim strTemp()
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    ReDim strTemp(1 To 2, 1 To col)
    vDB = Range("b5", Cells(Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, col))
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)


    For i = 1 To r Step 2
        For j = 1 To r Step 2
            'If vDB(j, x) > vDB(i, x) Then 'Ascent
            If vDB(j, x) < vDB(i, x) Then 'Descent

                For m = 1 To c
                    strTemp(1, m) = vDB(i, m)
                    strTemp(2, m) = vDB(i + 1, m)
                    vDB(i, m) = vDB(j, m)
                    vDB(i + 1, m) = vDB(j + 1, m)
                    vDB(j, m) = strTemp(1, m)
                    vDB(j + 1, m) = strTemp(2, m)
                Next
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("b5").Resize(r, c) = vDB
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error with this code. I placed it in the code worksheet. ByRef argument type mismatch